# Drawing line with AntiAlias = True, but it's still blurry

Tags: android, view, xamarin.android, draw, paint

I'm trying to draw sharp and crisp lines, but they're turning out blurry.  Any ideas on how to draw this at a higher resolution or draw with a scale or 2x or 4x or something?  In iOS when I draw I can simply apply a draw scale that will make it sharper, but I don't see anything like that in Android

Here's an example of what my lines are looking like after using this code to draw them.  I'm wondering if I need to give the view a size larger than "Match parent" but then give it the bounds of the parent or something...

--------------EDIT----------------
What my draw code currenty looks like:

```
            Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.Color = this.StringColor;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        paint.StrokeWidth = 1.0f;
        if (this.DoDashLines)
        {
            paint.SetPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { this.DashWidth, this.DashGap }, 0));
        }

        // Find the distance between points on X axis
        var distanceBetweenXAxis = Math.Abs(this.EndPoint.X - this.BeginPoint.X);
        var other = Math.Abs(this.BeginPoint.X - this.EndPoint.X);
        if (other > distanceBetweenXAxis)
        {
            distanceBetweenXAxis = other;
        }
        float controlPoint_offsetX = distanceBetweenXAxis * Studio_Canvas_StringBezierCurve_OffsetPerPixelX;
        // Enforce a minimum distance so it looks good
        float minDistanceX = 25;
        if (controlPoint_offsetX < minDistanceX)
        {
            controlPoint_offsetX = minDistanceX;
        }

        float controlPoint1_offsetX = controlPoint_offsetX;
        float controlPoint2_offsetX = controlPoint_offsetX;

        if (Math.Abs(this.BeginPoint.Y - this.EndPoint.Y) > 0.1f)
        {
            if (this.BeginPoint.X < this.EndPoint.X)
            {
                controlPoint1_offsetX *= 1f;
                controlPoint2_offsetX *= -1f;
            }
            else
            {
                controlPoint1_offsetX *= -1f;
                controlPoint2_offsetX *= 1f;
            }
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.MoveTo(this.BeginPoint.X, this.BeginPoint.Y);
        path.CubicTo(this.BeginPoint.X + controlPoint1_offsetX, this.BeginPoint.Y, this.EndPoint.X + controlPoint2_offsetX, this.EndPoint.Y, this.EndPoint.X, this.EndPoint.Y);

        canvas.DrawFilter = new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap);
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

[image]

Comment: You can try this  `canvas.DrawFilter = new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, PaintFlags.AntiAlias | PaintFlags.FilterBitmap);`

Comment: @MikeMa It looks the same to me with that line.  I feel like i'm doing something fundamentally wrong... Here's a dashed line I drew that looks blurry http://i.imgur.com/2GtWiL5.png

Comment: Try this Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); If the picture is still blurry, I think you need draw on  the Bitmap and then draw the Bitmap to the Canvas.

Comment: That didn't seem to do it either.  In the future i'll try drawing it as a bitmap, but i'm concerned that'll use a lot more memory and/or take significantly more time to draw.  But it'll take some experimentation for sure.